# enqueue script in wordpress plugin for specific hook

Tags: wordpress

When custom php function is called, need to register and enqueue script from within that called function. Then the whole thing gets added to wp_footer hook. 
the echoed div in code below shows up in the developer tool, but the script is not showing or even giving any errors, i.e.- if this were an issue with the file path, then there would be resource error, yes? Any comments as to why there wouldn't be an error in loading the script?

The code:

```
if(get_option('show_content')) { 

    function add_time() {
        echo '<div id="txt">' . '</div>';
        // add script tut pro word plugin dev ch12.3
        function py_enqueue_script () {

            wp_register_script( 'timescript', plugin_url('../time.js', __FILE__));
            wp_enqueue_script( 'timescript'); 

        } // end py_enqueue_script
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', py_enqueue_script);

    } // end show add_time

    add_action("wp_footer",add_time);

} // end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (spotted some syntax errors):

```
if(get_option('show_content')) { 

    function add_time() {
        echo '<div id="txt">' . '</div>';
        // add script tut pro word plugin dev ch12.3
        function py_enqueue_script () {

            wp_register_script( 'timescript', plugins_url('../time.js', __FILE__), false, null, false));
            wp_enqueue_script( 'timescript'); 

        } // end py_enqueue_script
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'py_enqueue_script');

    } // end show add_time

    add_action('wp_footer', 'add_time');

} // end if
```

- Brackets on add_action custom action (i.E. 'add_time' instead of add_time).
- Plugins URL Function goes plugins_url not plugin_url

Some very good additional article on enqueueing scripts: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/

Some additional info on plugins_url:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

Comment: ummm, oooops. That helped my knowledge base, but I'm still not get the script to come in. I put the script back into the add_date func and now the script sends the time to the page, however the time isn't updating. Maybe I need to use AJAX or something for that? I'll get it in another question-cheers ~